# Getting file size always zero when try from uri

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting uri using GET_CONTENT and also it works when used in Glide to show the image. But I am not getting file size. It always shows 0.

I tried using File(uri.path).length()

```
 fun fileSize(uri: Uri){
        var a = File(uri.path).length()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Uri` is not a file.

Add a dependency for [`DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile), such as `androidx.documentfile:documentfile`. Then, replace your code with:

```
fun fileSize(uri: Uri){
    var a = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(uri).length()
}
```

Comment: will this work with any uri? or it there any conditions?

Comment: @wangsun6: If you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, it should be OK in general. If you want, check the scheme of the `Uri`. If the scheme is `file`, then your original approach will work. If the scheme is `content`, then my approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `File` constructor takes a file system pathname as as its argument.  You have given it a "path" extracted from a URI which is probably not a pathname for a file system object.  (It might be if you are using a `file:` URL, but you are not checking the schema, so you can't be sure.)

If your `File` object has a pathname for a non-existent file, then when you call `File::length`, the documentation states that `length()` will return zero.

---

In the Java world you could try the following:

```
URI uri = ...
File file = new File(uri);
long length = file.length();
```

However, this only works if:

1. The `URI` is an absolute URI with a `file:` schema.
2. The file that the URI denotes exists in the local file system namespace.

(If 1. is not true, you get an exception.  If 2. is not true, you get a zero result.)

This should also work on the Android platform ... without adding any extra dependencies.